# Create hide button for navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've created this collapsable navbar that works nicely,

everytime scrolldown navbar show and everytime scrolltop navbar hide

I would like with show up navbar `hide bottom` is visible to users can hide navbar .

`show/hide button` should be scrollUP with navbar and everytime navar hiden this button visible to user !

Any way to do this?

```js
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  // Make sure they scroll more than delta
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

  // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
  // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
  } else {
    // Scroll Up
    if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

header {
  background: #f5b335;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
  bottom: -40px;
}

main {
  background: url() repeat;
  height: 2000px;
}

footer {
  background: #ddd;
}

* {
  color: transparent
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="nav-down">
  This is your menu.
</header>
<main>
  This is your body.
</main>
<footer>
  This is your footer.
</footer>
```

Anyone know of a good way to write this?
thanks for your helps............................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this solution.

> Edited

```js
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  // Make sure they scroll more than delta
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

  // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
  // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
    // Scroll Down
    if ($('header a').hasClass('Down-Arrow')){
    $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
    } else {
    $('.UP-Arrow').addClass('hide-arrow');
    }

  } else {
    // Scroll Up
    if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('.UP-Arrow').removeClass('hide-arrow');
      $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = st;
}

$(document).on('click','.Down-Arrow',function(){
$(this).removeClass('Down-Arrow').addClass('UP-Arrow');
$('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
});

$(document).on('click','.UP-Arrow',function(){
$(this).removeClass('UP-Arrow').addClass('Down-Arrow');
    $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

header {
  background: #f5b335;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

header a{
color:#000;
position:absolute;
width:30px;
height:30px;
padding:5px;
background:#f5b335;
bottom:40px;
right:20px;
border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
text-align:center;
transition-duration:0.3s;
cursor:pointer;
}

.Down-Arrow:after{
content: "˅";
position:absolute;
top:15px;
left:15px;
}

.UP-Arrow:after{
content: "˄";
position:absolute;
top:15px;
left:15px;
}

header.nav-up .Down-Arrow{
bottom:0px;
}

.hide-arrow{
bottom: -40px;
}

.nav-up {
  bottom: -40px;
}

main {
  background: url() repeat;
  height: 2000px;
}

footer {
  background: #ddd;
}

* {
  color: transparent
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="nav-down">
  This is your menu.
  <a class="Down-Arrow"></a>
</header>
<main>
  This is your body.
</main>
<footer>
  This is your footer.
</footer>
```

Comment: This is the literally the opposite thing of what you want. Button hides when scroll down but shows when scroll up...

Comment: @AhmedTagAmer i want this navbar visible just after `header` and before `footer  ` it should ?

Comment: @BijanZand , sorry i did not understand what you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this. I deleted the CSS `color: transparent` for you to see. All you need is setting `navbar`'s display `none` to `''`;

```js
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event) {
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  // Make sure they scroll more than delta
  if (Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
    return;

  // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
  // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
    // Scroll Down
    $('header').removeClass('nav-up');
    $('div').removeClass('nav-up');
  } else {
    // Scroll Up
    if (st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('header').addClass('nav-up');
      $('div').addClass('nav-up');
    }
  }

  lastScrollTop = st;
}

$("div").click(function(){
  $('header').slideToggle('fast', function() {
  $("div").css("bottom", $("div").css("bottom") === '30px' ? '10px' : '30px');
  });
 
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}

header {
  background: #f5b335;
  height: 40px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav-up {
  bottom: -40px !important;
}

main {
  height: 2000px;
}

footer {
  background: #ddd;
}

div {
  position: fixed;
  bottom:30px;
  right: 5px;
  background:#f5b335;
  border: 2px solid #f5b335;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: 0;
  transition: bottom 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="nav-down">
  This is your menu.
  
</header>
<div> Show Navbar </div>
<main>
  This is your body.
  
</main>

<footer>
  This is your footer.
</footer>
```

Comment: how set effect to scrolling down not fadeout!

Comment: and i want `hide botton` slide up with navbar and everytime navar hiden this botton visible to user !

Comment: Check it again, both nav and button hides when scroll up and when scroll down, you can see the hide nav button.

Comment: everytime navbar get hidden i want slidedown not fade left

Comment: You mean like this?

Comment: Possible when navbar is sliding up `Show Navbar` button stick that ? same with my sample

Comment: See My Update Post bro

Comment: What do you mean replace button to <button>

Comment: `<button> Show Navbar </button>` replace with `<div>Show Navbar </div> `